# Imagemagick setting colour from variable

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a line of my code which reads like this:

```
...
$gradient->newPseudoImage($ow, $oh, 'gradient:#3a7bd5-#3a6073');
...
```

This code works fine. However, if I try and do something like this:

```
...
$colour1 = '#3a7bd5';
$colour2 = '#3a6073';
$gradient->newPseudoImage($ow, $oh, 'gradient:$colour1-$colour2');
...
```

It doesn't work - am I doing something wrong here? I've tried a few variations on the above, such as leaving out the 's but to no avail. Sorry if this is something simple but I'm still learning PHP

Comment: Try changing the 'gradient:$colour1-$colour2' to "gradient:$colour1-$colour2"

Comment: @Bonzo Hi, unfortunately I did try that but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case - `'gradient:$colour1-$colour2'` will not take your variables. (Read more about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing))

Concat string with variables: `$gradient->newPseudoImage($ow, $oh, 'gradient:' . $colour1 . '-' . $colour2);`

Or better would be to format string like so:
`$gradient->newPseudoImage($ow, $oh, sprintf('gradient:%s-%s', $colour1, $colour2));`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried this ```$colour1 = #3a7bd5; $colour2 = #3a7bd5;``` in combination with ```$gradient->newPseudoImage($ow, $oh, sprintf('gradient:%s-%s', $colour1, $colour2));``` but didn't have any luck - do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: `<?php

    $colour1 = '#3a7bd5';
    $colour2 = '#3a7bd5';

    echo sprintf('gradient:%s-%s', $colour1, $colour2);`

Outputs: `gradient:#3a7bd5-#3a7bd5`. Make sure you put color codes as strings